# ModalDialog // change title when dialog openned

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I open popup modal dialog with something like this:

```
openInDialog: function (dlgWidth, dlgHeight, dlgAllowMaximize, dlgShowClose, needCallbackFunction, pageUrl) {
    var options = {
        autoSize: true,
        url: pageUrl, width: dlgWidth, height: dlgHeight, allowMaximize: dlgAllowMaximize,
        showClose: dlgShowClose
    };

if (needCallbackFunction) {
    options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, se_scripts.CloseDialogCallback);
}
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
```

}

And I want simply change title of this dialog when it's opened.

From this "List Name - Title" to this "List". Because my title has a strange system name. I have something like "List Name - WeirdoSystemTitle", so I don't want to scare users with this.

I use something like this:

```
var oldText= parent.document.getElementById("dialogTitleSpan");
var newText=oldText.textContent.split("-")[0];
SP.UI.UIUtility.setInnerText(parent.document.getElementById("dialogTitleSpan"), newText);
```

It works like a charm. But how to indicate when dialog is opened?

```
$(document).ready(changeTitle())
```

and

`SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', changeTitle );`

doesn't work.

Please help ^)

Answer (score 1):

Add the title to your options:

```
openInDialog: function (dlgWidth, dlgHeight, dlgAllowMaximize, dlgShowClose, needCallbackFunction, pageUrl) {
        var options = {
            autoSize: true,
            title: "List",
            url: pageUrl, width: dlgWidth, height: dlgHeight, allowMaximize: dlgAllowMaximize,
            showClose: dlgShowClose
        };

    if (needCallbackFunction) {
        options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, se_scripts.CloseDialogCallback);
    }
    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
```

Comment: that's exactly what I did as workaround. ^_^ but in that case I need to use jsom\csom for getting list name and then putting it as title in options. what do you think there's no easy way? I try to avoid requests to the server for better performance...

Comment: You don't have the list title at runtime? How else are you getting the pageUrl?

You could add your change title function to the view/edit form and query the url for `IsDlg=1`